# File Path When Including Nested Files in a Script

Tags: vbscript

I have a script file which opens a text file located in the same directory. Let's call it SubScript.

SubScript.vbs

```
 Function DoSomething(foo) 
 ...
    Dim Key
        With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Key = .OpenTextFile("key.txt", 1).ReadAll
    End With
  ...
  End Function
```

No problem here when the script is run on its own. However, I want to use the script above in another script file, "MainScript". The SubScript is located in a subfolder in the MainScript directory.

MainScript.vbs

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ExecuteGlobal .OpenTextFile(".\SubDir\SubScript.vbs", 1).ReadAll
End With
```

When I try and use the DoSomething function in the SubScript, I get a file not found error. I see what is happening, the subscript is trying to find the text file in the MainScript directory, where it doesn't exist.

Is there a way, without using an absolute file path, to make sure the SubScript loads the text file from the SubDir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative path is resolved wrt the current directory of the process. Sometimes you can use the script's folder to get more flexibility. But in your case (.ExecuteGlobal), the SubScript's current directory is the current directory of the MainScript.

You should pass a path to DoSomething(), unless you can live with hardcoding ".\SubDir\key.txt".

Comment: I can live with specifying the Subfolder in the path. Looks like the only way. Thanks.